# Using wildcard in rsyslog.conf $includeConfig

Tags: wildcard, rsyslog

I've looked around and haven't seen anyone else experiencing this issue. When using wildcards in $IncludeConfig, the expected config files are not loaded into rsyslog.

I've written a test configuration to show this happening.

This works:

```
$ModLoad     imuxsock.so
$ModLoad     imklog.so
$IncludeConfig     /etc/rsyslog.d/00-squid.conf
```

This does not work:

```
$ModLoad     imuxsock.so
$ModLoad     imklog.so
$IncludeConfig     /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
```

Nothing really going on in /etc/rsyslog.d/00-squid.conf:

```
local2.*     /var/log/test
```

When using the command, `logger -p local2.info THIS IS A TEST` I'd expect to see a log in /var/log/test. This only happens when I specify the config file explicitly.

This is being done on `CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)`

rsyslogd check:

```
>$ rsyslogd -N 1
rsyslogd: version 7.4.7, config validation run (level 1), master config /etc/rsyslog.conf
rsyslogd: End of config validation run. Bye.
```

Is there something simple I'm missing here?

Comment: It looks like it should work. Check for non-printing characters like carriage-return (`cat -vet rsyslog.conf`) You can also try just giving the directory `/etc/rsyslog.d/` to have all files included. Running with `-dn` will produce a lot of debug output in the foreground which might show something.

Comment: Adding debug logging: 

`$DebugFile /tmp/rsyslog_debug.log`
`$DebugLevel 2`

That helped a lot. It showed it was pulling the files in from rsyslog.d/ But I had a bad configuration in a file that I thought was loaded after 00. Seems I was wrong. Thanks for the help!